# Android & PHP: POST-ing data from Android to mysql db using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I need to pass login/register data from Android app to mysql database on localhost. I'm still in learning process, and have problem with this for last week. I read dozens of pages, questions & answers on Stack Overflow and tried everything but I just can't get this to work. Can You please point me the problem in my code, I'm still newbie regarding php and JSON.

Android, Activity & AsyncTask Class:

```
package com.example.mario.datadrivenassignmenttwo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class DbManager extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
}

public void register(View v) {
    EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    String username = uname.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("username is: " + username);
    String password = pw.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("password is: " + password);

    Uploader task = new Uploader();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://10.0.2.2/user_db/senddata.php", username, password });
}

public class Uploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        /* 
        String response = "Finished";
        try {
            postHttpContent(params[0],params[1],params[2]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.toString());
        }
        return response;
        */

        try {
            String urlParam = params[0];
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            String charset = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();

            String query = String.format("username=%s&password=%s", URLEncoder.encode(username, charset), URLEncoder.encode(password, charset));

            /*
            URLConnection conn = new URL(urlParam).openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

            OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            */

            URL url = new URL(urlParam);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(query);
            writer.close();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                System.out.println("It's ok!");
                System.out.println(query);

            } else {

                System.out.println("Error code there");

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
}
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php
// connect to database
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "user_db";


$link = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

// get the JSONArray the app sends
$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');

$jsonArray = json_decode($contents, true);
$jsonCount = count($jsonArray);

for ($i = 0; $i < $jsonCount; $i++) {
$item = $jsonArray[$i];
$itemUsername = utf8_decode($item['username']);
$itemPassword = utf8_decode($item['password']);
// parse the other json attributes here like the one above

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$itemUsername', '$itemPassword')";

if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
}
}

$link->close();
?>
```

There is a lot of commented code, that's all I have tried, and some other code as well, but nothing works. I also tried putting all the connection and rest into one method and calling that method inside AsyncTask class, that failed aswell.
Since I don't know PHP, I'm not sure if the problem is in my Android code or PHP file.

Many, many thanks in advance.

Comment: java.net.URLEncode returns your string as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  You can't use php://input with application/x-www-form encoding, try $_POST instead unless you really need to read the raw data. As its encoded as application/x-www-form then your json_decode will fail. You could change this >>> for ($i = 0; $i < $jsonCount; $i++) {
$item = $jsonArray[$i]; to  this >>> foreach ($jsonArray as $item) { but as its not json theres no need. If you use $_POST then $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] should contain your variables

Comment: @Mystiq. We need to know even if the app is running or not, what error codes you see. like what's going on. if you're printing logs of responses.

Comment: @Tonny Baya as You can see in code, i used few system.out lines, and all of them print correctly (i mean, all those variables I printed using system.out are correct). My variables conatin values from edit text. My query string that I write in stream goes like "username=user&password=pass"

And You can see that if block where if http connection is OK, it prints "It's ok!", and if connection is not OK, it prints "Error code there"...that if block prints "It's ok!", meaning connection is http_ok

Comment: @miknik I tried with $_POST as well, no luck either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out 10minutes ago. I'm posting new code now, and it works.

```
package com.example.korisnik.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class DbManager extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
}

public void register(View v) {
    EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    String username = uname.getText().toString();
    String password = pw.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Username is: " + username + " ,and password is: " + password);

    Uploader task = new Uploader();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://10.0.2.2/user_db/senddata.php", username, password });
}

public class Uploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String response = null;
        try {
            response += postHttpContent(params[0],params[1],params[2]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error");
            Log.e("error", e.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("JSON Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public String postHttpContent(String urlStr, String user, String pass) throws IOException, JSONException {
        String response = "";
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        JSONObject userdata = new JSONObject();
        userdata.put("username",user);
        userdata.put("password", pass);

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
        data.put(userdata);
        System.out.println("Array is: " + data);

        try {
            DataOutputStream localDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
            localDataOutputStream.writeBytes(data.toString());
            localDataOutputStream.flush();
            localDataOutputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Data writting: " + data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Data Output error");
        }

        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
            do {
                line = br.readLine();
                response += line;
            } while ((line = br.readLine()) != null);
        } else {
            response = "Error ";
            throw new IOException();
        }
        return response + " * Uploaded!";
    }
}
}
```

I used JSONObject and put key/value pairs of username and password in it. Than I put that JSONObject in JSONArray (I know it's just one JSONObject, and I didn't have to put it into JSONArray, but since my PHP code is "designed" for JSONArray, and I'm not good with PHP, I figured it's easier to put JSONObject into JSONArray, than to change PHP code which I don't understand very well.

Second change is using "DataOutputStream" instead of "OutputStreamWriter".

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand error codes. usually error codes in the 400's means you somehow hit the server but you are restricted to access resources or simply you just made bad request by providing wrong data. And error's in the 500's, those are normally sever errors. Which indicate  that there is a problem with your server code. Although note this as it's important to understand. When testing in local host, you need to expose your IP for your server to be to handle requests else you won't be able to hit your local host server. If you are a newbie checkout tools like Ngrok, will help you expose your IP faster so you can get the API's done. Goodluck Cheers!

Comment: Inside my app I don't get any error, and my "if block" that is supossed to excute only if connection is HTTP_OK, that block executes every time. That means my connection is good, I suppose.