# Xamarin Android, how do I send POST data to a PHP page in a MySQL database?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm aiming to create a register page that stores a users credentials in a MySQL database that uses Infinity Free to host.

I use PHP to get the POST values from the program to store in my database, however it simply doesn't work.

I'm doing this for a college project, albeit an important one so I could really use some help!

Code:

```
private async void MbtnDialogRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //User has clicked the Sign Up! button
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://......./*something*.php");

            HttpContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", mTxtUsername.Text),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", mTxtPassword.Text),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FirstName", mTxtName.Text),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Surname", mTxtSurname.Text),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Gender", mGender)
            });
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, formContent);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var responseResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Client_UploadValuesCompleted(sender, e);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "It didnt Work", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }

        private void Client_UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                mOnRegisterComplete.Invoke(this, new OnSignUpEventArgs(mTxtUsername.Text, mTxtPassword.Text, mTxtName.Text, mTxtSurname.Text, mGender));
                this.Dismiss();
            });
        }
```

PHP:

```
$servername = "EXPUNGED";
$database = "EXPUNGED";
$username = "EXPUNGED";
$password = "EXPUNGED";

try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo "Connected successfully";
    echo('<br>UN'. $_POST['Username']);
    echo('<br>PW' . $_POST['Password']);
    echo('<br>FN' . $_POST['FirstName']);
    echo('<br>SN' . $_POST['Surname']);
    echo('<br>GN' . $_POST['Gender']);


    if(isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['Password']) && isset($_POST['FirstName']) && isset($_POST['Surname']) && isset($_POST['Gender']))
    {

    //Get the POST variables
    $mUsername = $_POST['Username'];
    $mPassword = $_POST['Password'];
    $mFirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $mSurname = $_POST['Surname'];
    $mGender = $_POST['Gender'];

    echo "Variables received and set";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO USERS (Username, Password, FirstName, Surname, Gender) VALUES (:un, :pw, :fn, :sn, :gn)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':un', $mUsername);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pw', $mPassword);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fn', $mFirstName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sn', $mSurname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gn', $mGender);

    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";

    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

$conn = null;
?>

I've already established that my PHP definitely works as I've been able to input data into the database by creating a rough HTML and sending hard values through there, it seems to be the Xamarin Android file that I can't work out.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Do you get a compiler or runtime error?  Does it throw an exception?  Have you verified the server is reachable from your device/emulator?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: also, `response.StatusCode` is valuable information.  If it is not OK, then what is it?  That error code can tell you a lot about the problem.

Comment: You could use `HttpURLConnection` .Here is a similar issue which maybe can help you . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458597/android-php-post-ing-data-from-android-to-mysql-db-using-php . The solution is in native Android , and you just need to convert it to Xamarin.Android .

Comment: You're right @Jason I should have been more specific in stating my problem. The problem is that it runs the next piece of code, meaning that 'response.StatusCode' is returning OK. However the database is not updated. I already said that my PHP works when sending POST variables through a sample HTML page, so is there something else I need to do to allow the PHP to receive variables from Xamarin.Android?

Comment: It appears that your PHP will return OK no matter what happens.  Have you checked the server logs?  What about all those echo statements?  They should be present in the response so you can check their values.

Comment: I used the echo statements from the response and it turns out the web API I was using was blocking my PHP from working for some reason and I couldn't change the settings, I'm using something different now and it all works fine, thank you for helping.